# Is there a command to return the owner of a file?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Is there a shell command to just print the owner of a file?

I guess I could just do:

```
ls -l  | awk '{print $3}'
```

but this feels like there would be a more straightforward answer to the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `stat(1)`

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ stat -c %U file.c
cnicutar
```

There are lots of format sequences available: user ID, total size, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this leaves a much better taste in my mouth

Comment: In Mac OS X, it's `stat -f "%Su" file.c`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `find` command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'file.c' -printf '%u\n'
```